How to figure out what kind of complement it is?
How can I know whether it's subject or object complement? For example:

He leaves the court a free man (subject complement, because he is a free man).
He leaves him a free man (object complement, I suppose, the person represented by object "him" is a free man, isn't it?).
He leaves it a free man (I'm confused, is it subject or object complement?).


Why would you think 1) He leaves the court a free man and 3) He leaves it a free man might be different? The most likely referent of it is probably a court anyway, so they'd normally be the same meaning as well as the same structure.

Neither. They are predicative but adjuncts not complements. I'd call them predicative adjuncts: predicative because they relate to a predicand ("he") and adjuncts because they are optional modifiers in clause structure.

You've struck on a confusing construction here, because yes, it works both ways. The good news is that, either way, it's not a terribly common construction, and you're never obligated to use it. It's often easier to use simpler language, like "As he left the court he was a free man."
Number 2 is the most ambiguous; in fact it could be taken either way. 1 and 3 are saved from ambiguity only because a court isn't a man, and "a man" doesn't usually take the pronoun "it."
The good news first of all is that we don't encounter sentences in isolation. We would rely on context to clarify. Somebody's freedom is the topic here, and it ought to be clear whose.
The next bit of good news is that extra bits of punctuation or words could help.

He leaves him, a free man.

This comma helps attach "a free man" to the first "he." It doesn't totally remove ambiguity, because we can use this comma both ways ("He left Detroit, penniless and hungry" and "He left Detroit, the coldest city he had been to yet"), but it steers us to a choice.

He leaves him as a free man.

Adding "as" makes it clear here that it's the subject "he" that the phrase modifies.
And of course the final bit of good news is, as I said at first, that you wouldn't encounter this usage out of context, and can usually find more natural constructions if you're writing.

A more recent (and more accurate) term for such expression is 'predicative adjunct: predicative because they relate to a predicand ("he", or "him") and adjuncts because they are optional modifiers in clause structure.

I don't think there's any grammatical test that can distinguish these.
Your 2 is formally ambiguous. However, I think that without any context that determines otherwise, people would take it as an object complement; so if it is intended as a subject complement, people would be inclined to put a comma before "a free man". (This might not be wholly successful: there could be contexts where it would be an object complement even with a comma).

Has a subject complement by semantics.


The ambiguity in #2 is simply because we can't know whether he and him refer to the same or different people. Which imho makes it a poor example in the first place. No such issue arises with 2a) She leaves him a free man.

I wouldn't say they were either subject or object complements, in fact not complements at all. A more recent (and more accurate) term for such expression is 'predicative adjunct: predicative because they relate to a predicand ("he", or "him") and adjunct because they are optional modifiers in clause structure.
